# Variance of log return

Tags: statistics, logarithms, variance

Suppose $C_i$ is i-day's closed price, when drift is small,
we have the close to close variance
$$\sigma^2 =\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits^n_{i = 1}\left(\log\left(\dfrac{C_i}{C_{i-1}}\right)\right)^2.$$
If we adjust this for the drift,
$$\sigma^2 =\dfrac{1}{n-1}\sum\limits^n_{i = 1}\left(\left(\log\left(\dfrac{C_i}{C_{i-1}}\right)\right)^2 - \dfrac{\log\left(\left(\dfrac{C_n}{C_0}\right)\right)^2}{n(n-1)}\right).$$
I don't know how to obtain the later one in the bracket? I know the original one should be
$$\left(\log\left(\dfrac{C_i}{C_{i-1}}\right) - \dfrac{\log\left(\dfrac{C_n}{C_0}\right)}{n}\right)^2$$

Comment: The $n(n-1)$ denominator is strange.  Where did you see this expression?

Comment: @Guangliang could you deduce it specifically? Book `Paul Wilmott on Quantitative Finance` `page 819`

Comment: No, I don't know where that denominator come from.  I don't have the book you mentioned.  I have a different book ("Option Pricing") of his (co-authored with others).  On p. 25 of "Option Pricing", he has something different: $$\bar m = \frac1{ndt}\sum_{i=1}^n\log(S_{i+1}/S_i)$$ and $$\bar\sigma^2 = \frac1{(n-1)dt}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\log(S_{i+1}/S_i)-\bar m\right)^2.$$  It doesn't have the $n(n-1)$ denominator.

Comment: @Guangliang I may don't agree with above formula, $\bar{m}$ is annualized, but $\log(S_{i+1}/S_i)$ is not annualied.